# Firefox 42 cannot access one SSL website

Tags: nginx, ssl, firefox

The website https://tremplinsdelimaginaire.com/ recently upgrade ciphers and SSL configuration. Old browsers don't work anymore, but Firefox 42 on Ubuntu 14.04 does not work (secured connection failed, with no possibility to access the website, no certificate to read, nothing). 
The webmaster of the site does not have any problem, Firefox 42 on Debian. I suspect one library, but wich one ? Others websites seems to work well. I ask for the webserver configuration.

Comment: Are you the administrator of this site?

Comment: Is there any sort of more detailed error message available?

Comment: I am not, but I know him (and he don't understand the problem).

Comment: The error is (in french) "Échec de la connexion sécurisée

La connexion avec le serveur a été réinitialisée pendant le chargement de la page.

    La page que vous essayez de consulter ne peut pas être affichée car l'authenticité des données reçues ne peut être vérifiée.
    Veuillez contacter les propriétaires du site web pour les informer de ce problème."

Comment: My translation : "Secured connection failed. Connection with the server was reinitialized during the page loading. The page you are trying to watch can't be displayed because the authenticity of receveid data can't be verified. Please contact the owner of the website to inform them about this problem."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The site works for me with Firefox 42 on Ubuntu 14.04 but it clearly says that:

> Connection is not secure

and further explains

> Parts of the page are not secure (such as images)

If you look into the browser console you see more details, like:

```
> Blocked loading mixed active content "http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald"[Learn More] site
> Loading mixed (insecure) display content "http://tremplinsdelimaginaire.com/site/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/logTremplinTemp.png" on a secure page[Learn More]
```

Same problem with Chrome too.

But, if the site does not load all you might have distrusted critical CA certificates. I recommend that you retry with a fresh browser profile because this uses the default set of trusted CA. This should also resolve problems coming from the use of HPKP with keys which are no longer used by the site.

Comment: Ok for images, the website webmaster is aware of this. I have the problem on two differents Ubuntu 14.04, and I have to understand why it's ok for you. Maybe a missing CA certificates, you're right.

Comment: Great, you're rigth : with a new profile it run fine. I just tried safe mode, not another profiles. So I just have to understand how to repair my profils :-D